# In Vscode, how to code in different terminals by storing code in OneDrive

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, warnings, onedrive

I got two computers and I want to continue coding for my program when I take my laptop to the library. So I moved the code file from OS(C:) to OneDrive. But it doesn't work and show warnings. In launch.json, I have a line for "cwd". What should I do to handle this? Thx!

Comment: Have you tried using git?

Comment: No, it's the problems with OneDrive, I've recoverd the location of all the backup files, and it works. Maybe OneDrive is better for storing some temporary files.

Comment: Your code has maybe hidden files. Which will not synced via OneDrive. Also Winodws (even 10 and 11) has still some path length limits (~250 charrs) your onedrive location is often inside `C:\Users\[YourUsername]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneDrive\`, you may reach the limit

Comment: as Mario Parez said. use GIT, there are several free services out there you could use. 
and using a GIT helps you a lot, for example, imagine your code was working yesterday. and today after 2-3 hours of work it suddenly stopped working. with GIT if used correctly you can switch back to a working version of your application and pick it up from there. 
But first you should learn how to use GIT. its very useful knowing how to use and also some companies asko to see your GIT if you have. and knowing how to use a git is sometimes a requirement (not always)